# how to update the display of my CheckBox items in my ListView marked as check?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-adapter, android-checkbox

When I first run my app, the `CheckBox` items in my `ListView` are unchecked. In my `layout.xml` I have a single `CheckBox` above my `ListView` items. When that single `CheckBox` above my `ListView` is checked it should mark all the `CheckBox` items in my `ListView` as checked. My code below does not update the display of my `CheckBox` items in my `ListView` as checked but when I tried to get the boolean of each `CheckBox` item in my `ListView` by calling `checkItem.isChecked()` and let it display in my `logcat`, it returns true. Did I miss something?

```
package com.usjr.sss.fragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.usjr.sss.R;
import com.usjr.sss.activity.CourseFragmentActivity;
import com.usjr.sss.adapter.InfoTechAdapter;
import com.usjr.sss.adapter.SubjectDbAdapter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class InfoTechFirstYearFragment extends Fragment {

private CheckBox checkFirstYearFirstSem;
private ListView listItFirstYearFirstSem;
private ListView listItFirstYearSecondSem;
private InfoTechAdapter infoTechAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_it_first_year, container,
            false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("InfoTechFirstYearFragment", "onActivityCreated");

    listItFirstYearFirstSem = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
            R.id.listItFirstYearFirstSem);
    listItFirstYearSecondSem = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
            R.id.listItFirstYearSecondSem);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i("InfoTechFirstYearFragment", "onStart");

    SubjectDbAdapter subjectDbAdapter = new SubjectDbAdapter(getActivity());
    subjectDbAdapter.open();

    Cursor cursor = subjectDbAdapter.fetchAllSubjects();
    ArrayList<String> arrayListSubject = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayListFirstSem = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayListSecondSem = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String subject = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(SubjectDbAdapter.SUBJECT_ID));
        arrayListSubject.add(subject);
    }// end while

    subjectDbAdapter.close();

    int index;

    /**
     * 1st yr 1st sem
     */
    for (index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
        arrayListFirstSem.add(arrayListSubject.get(index));
    }

    infoTechAdapter = new InfoTechAdapter(
            (CourseFragmentActivity) getActivity(), arrayListFirstSem);
    listItFirstYearFirstSem.setAdapter(infoTechAdapter);

    /**
     * 1st yr 2nd sem
     */
    for (index = 9; index < 18; index++) {
        arrayListSecondSem.add(arrayListSubject.get(index));
    }

    infoTechAdapter = new InfoTechAdapter(
            (CourseFragmentActivity) getActivity(), arrayListSecondSem);
    listItFirstYearSecondSem.setAdapter(infoTechAdapter);

    /**
     * MARK ALL THE CHECKBOX AS CHECKED
     */
    checkFirstYearFirstSem = (CheckBox) getActivity().findViewById(
            R.id.checkFirstYearFirstSem);
    checkFirstYearFirstSem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (checkFirstYearFirstSem.isChecked()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ckecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                int count = listItFirstYearFirstSem.getCount();
                for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {

                    // View viewMy =
                    // listItFirstYearFirstSem.getChildAt(index);
                    // Object id = v.getTag();

                    View viewItem = (View) listItFirstYearFirstSem
                            .getAdapter().getView(index, getView(),
                                    listItFirstYearFirstSem);
                    CheckBox checkItem = (CheckBox) viewItem
                            .findViewById(R.id.subject);
                    checkItem.setChecked(true);

                    listItFirstYearFirstSem.setItemChecked(index, true);

                    infoTechAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.i("checkItem",
                            String.valueOf(checkItem.getText().toString()));
                    Log.i("checkItem",
                            String.valueOf(checkItem.isChecked()));
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "unckecked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }// end if-else(checkFirstYearFirstSem.isChecked())
        }// end onClick
    });// end OnClickListener
}// end onStart()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself yey!

Instead of using

```
View viewItem = (View) listItFirstYearFirstSem.getAdapter().getView(index, getView(), listItFirstYearFirstSem);
```

I used

```
View viewItem = listItFirstYearFirstSem.getChildAt(index);
```

Then

```
CheckBox checkItem = (CheckBox) viewMy.findViewById(R.id.subject);
checkItem.setChecked(true);
```